# is "I hadn't had breakfast." correct?

Tags: grammar

I'm a newbie in this community. I doubt the legitimacy of the above sentence.
Can I use it when I'm talking about an action in the past?

Comment: It's all good. You could be answering "How could you eat all that food at lunchtime?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct, as long as the start and end of the action are both in the past.
E.g.

> That winter morning that I was out hunting, I hadn't had breakfast.

Comment: Thank you for your help.